# Error Code in simple function

Tags: haskell

```
verdopple :: Integer -> Integer
verdopple x = x + x
```

When I try to run the previous code into GHCi I get the following error:

```
No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
    (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?) arising from a sue of 'print'
    In a stmt on an interactice GHCi command: print it
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't know how to print your function.  You can invoke it with an argument, then it will show you the result.

Comment: Stackoverflow has been getting lots of Haskell questions lately that look like people attempting Haskell without any course or book to guide them through the first steps. I'm curious where this is coming from - what inspired you to attempt your first Haskell program, and what inspired you to create an account on Stackoverflow as the way to solve your problem?

Comment: @DanielMartin: Apparently, there's a new course in… Munich? Given that `verdopple` is German, OP might also attend that course. But I'm not sure about that yet.

Comment: @DanielMartin: Haskell is part of my computer science course that I just started. Unfortunately it is the very first programming language we are learning. Looking back at my question my mistake was pretty obvious. I could not find the answer in our script so  I turned to the Internet and found Stackoverflow. Thanks alot for your help!
Oh and Germany is right, the place is Frankfurt though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because at the ghci prompt, you did something like this:

```
*Main> verdopple
```

This is asking ghci to print out your function, and its error message is telling you "I can't print functions".

Try asking for `verdopple 5` or `:type verdopple`.